# WPF equivalent of margin-top?

Tags: wpf, margin

How do you do the equivalent of css's margin-top in WPF?

I have an image which I want to add a margin on the top, but all I can seem to get to work is margin, which effects each side of the image.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can specify the margin for each side (in that order : left, top, right, bottom)

```
<Image Source="image.png" Margin="0,10,0,0"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies.  I only tried Margin="10 0" thinking that would set the top and bottom to 10 and the sides to 0.

I should have figured this one out on my own.  Thanks!

Comment: WPF will let you do Margin="10,0" but the first number is the sides, the second is top/bottom.

Answer (score 8):

the Margin property is what you are looking for. There are 3 different ways to set the margin.  The first one (see below) sets all of the margins to the same value--it expands out to "0,0,0,0".
the second one sets the left and right sides to 1 and the top and bottom sides to 0--it expands out to "1,0,1,0". and the third sets each side to an individual value (in this case, 5).
  Margin values, in order:first  value is left side
                          second value is top
                          third  value is right side
                          fourth value is bottom

```
Margin="5";      <!-- same as "5,5,5,5" -->
Margin="5,2"     <!-- same as "5,2,5,2" -->
Margin="5,6,7,8" <!-- set left,top,right,bottom independantly -->
```

Comment: MS documentation on FrameworkElement.Margin indicates that Margin="#,#" is used for specifying symetrical margins. So "5,2" is the same as "2.5,1,2.5,1"

Comment: hmm, doesn't seem to work that way when in any of my code--could just be me, tho.

Comment: 5,2,5,2 is symmetrical as well and is how it actually works in practice.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the left, top, right, bottom numbers to specify the margin for any control in WPF

For example:

```
<Button Margin="10 5 10 10" />
```

Here Left -> 10, Top -> 5, Right - 10 and Bottom -> 10

For more check this blog post
[WPF Margin demystified](http://vkreynin.wordpress.com/2008/10/13/wpf-margin-demystified/)

Another useful blog post about [Margins, Padding, Borders and Content](http://www.danrigsby.com/blog/index.php/2008/05/20/margins-and-padding-in-wpf/), nice one

Answer (score 2):

You can use margin and vertical alignment.

For example:

```
<Button Margin="0,200,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```